# Video tag not working in ipad, but works in Android

Tags: php, html, video, mobile

any idea why this code isn't working? Seems to be working on android phones and tablets, but my friend just tried an ipad and there wasn't any video. I'm all thumbs with iOS, I'm not ever sure how to debug this. Here's my php snippet. Thanks.

```
if ($mobile_browser > 0) {
     print "<video  height='320' width='480' autoplay='autoplay' controls='controls' >";
     print "<source src='file.mp4' type='video/mp4' />";
     print "</video>";
```

Comment: Do you know anything about how the video was encoded?

Comment: Yep, I encoded it in Vegas. I also used an application to move the mp4 metadata to the beginning of the file to allow it to stream properly in my flash-based player. Is the ipad touchy on what mp4 files it can handle? I didn't even consider this.

Comment: Take a look at this thread: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3131588?start=0&tstart=0.

Comment: I'm not exactly an expert in PHP, but how do you populate the $mobile_browser var? Are you sure you're detecting the iPad as a mobile browser?

Comment: is your video a MPEG4 with H264 video and AAC audio codec?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed garrett's link and saw the part about MIME types. I put in an mp4 MIME type in apache and off to the races we go!